# wp_login_form display no styled form

Tags: functions, customization, login, wp-login-form

I've created a custom template for a custom theme, I need to show the vue app that will manage the front end only to logged users. I've used this code inside my functions.php file
and it's supposed that I will have a custom login form.

functions.php

```php
<?php 
/*
* Form customizzato per Login sito OH
*/
function custom_login_form(){
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #fff !important;
            }
            #login h1 a {
                background-image: url('...');
                background-size: contain;
                height: 86px;
                width: 320px;
                background-position: center center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
            #loginform {
                border-radius: 5% !important;
            }
            #nav {
                display: none !important;
            }
            #backtoblog a {
                display: none !important;
            }
            #language-switcher {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>
    <?php   
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_login_form');

?>
```

app.php template file

```php
<?php 
/*
* Template name: App
*/
wp_head();

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {

?>
    <div id="app"></div>
<?php

} else {
    wp_login_form();
}

wp_footer();
?>
```

Is there something wrong in the code or I need to pass params to `wp_login_form()`?

[image: login form]

Answer (score 1):

The form appeared un-styled because the [`login_enqueue_scripts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_enqueue_scripts/) does not run on the front-end/non-admin side ( unless you do `do_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts' )` in your template ).

So try using [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) instead: `add_action('wp_head', 'custom_login_form');`.

You should also add the custom CSS only on the app page, or when the template being used is `app.php`. For example, you can add this check at the top in your `custom_login_form` function:

```php
// Do nothing if the template is not app.php.
// This will work the file is at wp-content/themes/your-theme/app.php.
if ( ! is_page_template( 'app.php' ) ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your suggested solution, but seems not work. If I replace `login_enqueue_scripts` with `wp_head` into the functions.php file, nothing change. So I've tried with `do_action` inside the template into the else block, but nothing. The form will stay unstyled

Comment: Try again with `wp_head` and check the HTML source of the page, then see if your custom CSS is in the source, e.g. find `#loginform { border-radius: 5% !important; }`. If you see it, then it means the CSS is being added, so you just need to tweak your CSS rules. But you'll need to do that yourself.

Comment: The css is added with both the hooks. The problem is that from the `wp-login.php` page that is where the css works perfectly and the template page where I've added the form, all the html markup of the form is different. Is not possible to have exactly the same default form that will works with `login_enqueue_scripts` ?

Comment: The css is used mainly for the wp-login page, but I need to have login page as default index before users can use the vue app that will manage front-end

Comment: *I posted this answer just to let you know that you've used the wrong hook to add your custom CSS.* I can't help you with replicating the `wp-login.php` page, and neither with CSS tweaking, but as for the latter, you could basically add the relevant class/id to your elements and just copy the [CSS used on the `wp-login.php` page](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.2.2/wp-admin/css/login.css) to your custom login page.

Comment: ok, thank you. Since I never used this function before, I didn't know that the form will be displayed unstyled. I will do my best to customize it otherwise, is there also an hook to show the login page for all users when they open the website?

Comment: If I correctly understand that, then one example is the [`template_redirect` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) which you can use to redirect non logged-in users to your custom login page when they land on your website. But for further assistance regarding that, you should post a new question and be as detailed as possible.

Comment: And actually, since you're creating a Vue app, then you should learn the proper ways of creating it - see examples/guides [here](https://wptips.dev/wp-login-with-vue/), [here](https://kinsta.com/blog/headless-wordpress/#how-to-make-wordpress-headless-build-an-app) & [here](https://wpmudev.com/blog/creating-a-hybrid-single-page-app-wordpress-with-vuejs/).